# Returning 2 arrays from subroutine depending on stop list

Tags: perl

This has been moved to a test case [here](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=912276).

### RE-DONE:

I want to return arrays (must be references) from 2 subroutines, however the regex used as a conditional statement isn't working as I'd hoped. I've tried doing it with one, but I figure this will be easier.

To be clear, my goal is to have an array of matches sorted (`@all_matches`), and then add on another array (`@all_pronoun_matches`) sorted the same way but added at the **end**.

This is the `@pronoun_matches` subroutine:

```
my ($line, $verbform, $chapternumber, $sentencenumber, $sentence) = @_;
my @matches;
my @pronoun_matches;
return unless ($line =~ /(\w+)\((\w+)\-\d+\,\s(\w+)\-\d+\)/); #2nd repeat check     
$grammar_relation = $1;
$argument1 = $2;
$argument2 = $3;
    
return if (($argument1 =~ /^$argument2/i)||($argument2 =~ /^$argument1/i));    

foreach my $pronoun (@stopListNoun)
    {
    if ((lc $pronoun eq lc $argument1) || (lc $pronoun eq lc $argument2)) 
        {
        push (@pronoun_matches, $chapternumber, $sentencenumber, $sentence, $grammar_relation, $argument2, $argument1) if ($argument2 =~ /$verbform/i);
        push (@pronoun_matches, $chapternumber, $sentencenumber, $sentence, $grammar_relation, $argument1, $argument2) if ($argument1 =~ /$verbform/i);
        }
    else
        {return}
    }
    
return (\@pronoun_matches);
```

The `@matches` has a very similar subroutine except this:

```
foreach my $pronoun (@stopListNoun) #Just a list of words
    {
    return if ((lc $pronoun eq lc $argument1) || (lc $pronoun eq lc $argument2));
    }
    
    push (@matches, $chapternumber, $sentencenumber, $sentence, $grammar_relation, $argument2, $argument1) if ($argument2 =~ /$verbform/i); ##USED TO BE 'eq', but that prevented protective from showing
    push (@matches, $chapternumber, $sentencenumber, $sentence, $grammar_relation, $argument1, $argument2) if ($argument1 =~ /$verbform/i);
    
    return \@matches;
```

This is called by:

```
my $matches;
my $pronoun_matches;
$matches = &dependency_checks($lines[$l], $verbform, $chapternumber, $sentencenumber, $sentence);
$pronoun_matches = &pronoun_dependency_checks($lines[$l], $verbform, $chapternumber, $sentencenumber, $sentence);
push @all_matches, $matches if ($matches);
push @all_pronoun_matches, $pronoun_matches if ($pronoun_matches);
```

To send to the print section *after* being sorted using hashes, I'd like to use:

`@all_matches = (@all_matches, @all_pronoun_matches);` However, `@all_pronoun_matches` has 0 matches (or they are being filtered somewhere).

### Question

Why does `@all_pronoun_matches` have uninitialized values in it??
After some testing, I've found that the match never gets passed the conditional statement, but it's the same as the one in the `@matches` subroutine!

---

Originally, I had just wanted to remove the pronouns and it worked fine, so I know the condition works:

```
foreach my $pronoun (@stopListNoun)
        {
        return if ((lc $pronoun eq lc $argument1) || (lc $pronoun eq lc $argument2));
        }
```

I've tried using an if-else in the foreach and combining the subroutines, but then all the matches (including pronouns) went into `@all_matches` despite being called correctly (this method was posted here before).

Let me know if anything is unclear about my intent or the problem.

Comment: `@all_matches = @matches, @all_pronoun_matches;`  What do you think that does?

Comment: Okay, Sorry, notice the edit: `@all_matches = (@all_matches, @all_pronoun_matches);`

Comment: Sorry to previous visitors, I have redone the problem because it got out of hand. DavidO and ysth's comments/answers were posted BEFORE it was redone.

Comment: I think you need to give us more to go on.  Like show us more of the subs and how you are iterating over the lines.

Comment: I'm trying to think of what to include, but this is all I can see affecting it. It'd probably be easier if I just asked how people would do it from scratch... I really think it has to do with the push inside the foreach (in the subroutine) not working as I expect (not getting any matches)

Comment: I have started fresh at http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=912276

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@all_matches = @matches, @all_pronoun_matches;
```

should be

```
@all_matches = ( @matches, @all_pronoun_matches );
```

, has lower precedence than =

If you had warnings enabled, you would have gotten a [Useless use of a variable in void context](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Useless-use-of-%25s-in-void-context) warning alerting you that @all_pronoun_matches didn't become part of the assignment.

Comment: Thanks, I was using CGI::Carp, guess doesn't catch it. BUT that still doesn't solve the problem of the `@matches` containing things it isn't supposed to.

Comment: Likely a problem in the parts you aren't showing us.  Find a single call to dependency_checks that is returning the wrong thing and go from there..

Comment: CGI::Carp is a handler for errors, but it doesn't itself generate warnings.  There is almost no reason for not putting `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of all scripts while they're being developed.

Comment: Sorry, I do have `use strict; use warnings;` at the top. Just forgot to check the error_log. What I don't get is that it used to work, when all I wanted to do was eliminate pronouns, not keep them separate (as shown at bottom of question). Thanks though

Comment: You may want to say `use warnings 'FATAL' => 'all';` :)

Comment: Thanks. I think the first step is find how to eliminate the uninitialized in `@all_pronoun_matches`, or get `@matches` back to how it was without the pronouns